# create a directory based on a users IP address

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a directory based on a users IP address, my desired result would be the IP address stripped of "." example: uploads/524362598745
my code only creates "uploads/$ip"

```
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

if (!file_exists('uploads/$ip')) {
    mkdir('uploads/$ip', 0777, true);
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't strip the dots in the `$ip`; and not to having it, is good!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the single quotes (`'`) to double quotes (`"`) in the `mkdir()` function.

> Unlike the [double-quoted](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) and [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntaxes, variables and escape
>   sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur
>   in [single quoted](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) strings.

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't parse variables in single quotes (`'`), only in double quotes (`"`). Your `mkdir` statement needs to be:

```
mkdir("uploads/$ip", 0777, true);
```

Or, if you prefer, use concatenation:

```
mkdir('uploads/' . $ip, 0777, true);
```

To strip the periods, you just need something like this:

```
$ip = str_replace('.', '', $ip);
```

Keep in mind that this *will not* result in unique directory names. The addresses `12.34.56.78` and `123.45.6.78`, for example, would result in the same directory name, as would many, many other examples.

Also, please note that what you are doing has a lot of serious security implications. It's hard to say what the best approach is without knowing more about your needs, but this is probably not it.

Comment: I'm trying to create a "Unique" "Temp" upload directory so files may be zipped, emailed and deleted

Comment: Well, it won't be unique, and it won't be at all secure unless you add some authentication. You need to prevent a clever bad guy from grabbing the files by just guessing IP addresses. This is especially problematic with, for example, coffee shop WiFi, in which many users may share a single, easily-determined, IP address, and the bad guy can easily detect traffic to your server.